# Is there a way to automatically get changes from github on a nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, github

So I have a website (lets say banana.com) and I have to go to school (every day obviously), but I want to be able to edit it from school. I have the server running on Node.js on a raspberry pi so of course it is not a huge consumer website; it's more just a learning and fun thing.

What I've come up with so far is

a. have source code on GitHub
b. use vscode online to edit the source code
c. download changes and restart (with something like nodemon) **This is what I'm stuck on..**

anyone have any suggestions? I know I can use something like [replit](https://replit.com/) but that's not very good as it is just slow, and I know even my raspberry pi is way better.

Also I think I should mention I'm not very experienced with either github or nodejs, I'm just using them to host my website.

Comment: You could have an admin feature of your website (available only to your admin login) that tells your server to fetch a new copy of its code from Github, then shut-down and restart.  You could do those steps from a shell script that you run from your server using a child_process.  And, then if nodemon (or something similar is monitoring your server, you just shut your server down) and let nodemon restart it with the updated code.

Comment: This is called CI (continuous delivery). With github you can do it with [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions); basically, you instruct your Github repository (with a .yml config file) to execute arbitrary code given a codition. A very basic example: after every push on the master branch, this script is executed by github's servers; with this script you could access with SSH to your Raspberry, pull the new changes and restart the node.js process. [Here](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) you can find some example